# How to extend strapi admin user attributes

Tags: strapi

I couldn't find answer to this question anywhere so here it is:

Let's say I have a collection type Article and I managed to include data (first, last name and email) of the author that wrote it (Admin User) through life-cycles and save it in a hidden field Author of type JSON.

Now I get in my response all these fields about the author, but I would also like to get an image of the author, which means I would like to add an "Image" attribute to the Admin User and then update my life-cycle for this.

**Since this model is create via strapi-admin plugin (I assume?), how can I extend this to get the image attribute field in there as well? Or is there a better approach?**

I am using Strapi v3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only option is to fork the `strapi-admin` package as it's not a plugin (yet, see the following request: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4838) you can't currently customize the backend.

To fork, in this context, is to take the package and throw it into something like `./packages` and reference that in your `package.json` like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "strapi": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-admin": "file:packages/strapi-admin",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-documentation": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-utils": "3.1.4"
  },
```